# What does this code do, and what does it look like in C?

Tags: ida, x86

I'm using IDA to disassemble a file, and one of the sections contained this. What is this doing? What would it look like in C?

I believe it pushes edx onto the stack, and converts it to an integer using _atoi, but what is left in eax after that, and why is it comparing it to 5?

```
mov     ecx, [ebp+argv]
mov     edx, [ecx+4]
push    edx             ; char *
call    _atoi
add     esp, 4
mov     [ebp+var_60], eax
cmp     [ebp+var_60], 5
jle     short loc_401167
```

Edit: Got a great answer, also another good answer here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33535720/what-does-this-code-do-and-what-does-it-look-like-in-c/33535891#33535891

Comment: What's with the downvote? Just curious, I always want to make my questions better. No comment after the downvote doesn't help though.

Comment: Not the downvoter, but i think the problem is the same reason as the one for the close vote: "Questions asking for help reverse-engineering a specific system are off-topic unless they demonstrate an understanding of the concepts involved and clearly identify a specific problem"

Comment: Hmm. I could post the rest of the code that I've already disassembled, to prove my "understanding," but I thought this was just a curious problem. I asked a specific set of questions, stated what my understanding so far was, and posted legitimate assembly code. I got it answered over at stackoverflow anyways.

Comment: "I got it answered over at stackoverflow anyways" -- please don't cross-post, or at least mention that and link the questions, to stop people from putting needless effort into questions that already have a solution.

Comment: No problem; won't do that again. Will link to overflow in an edit to the main post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

seems to be unoptimized compilation anyway if you were using ollydbg and compiled this code with debug information ollydbg will show the source code in the next column

source used

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main (int argc , char* argv[]) {
  if(argc!=2){return -1;}
  signed int foo =0;
  if((foo = atoi(argv[1])) > 5) {goto blah;}
  printf("notok");return 0;
  blah:
  printf("ok");return 1;
}
```

compiled with no optimisations

**cl /Zi /EHsc /nologo /W4 /analyze *.cpp /link /RELEASE**

```
00401000 a>PUSH    EBP                         ; {
00401001   MOV     EBP, ESP
00401003   PUSH    ECX
00401004   CMP     DWORD PTR SS:[EBP+8], 2     ; if(argc!=2){return -1;}
00401008   JE      SHORT atoitest.0040100F
0040100A   OR      EAX, FFFFFFFF
0040100D   JMP     SHORT atoitest.00401055
0040100F   MOV     DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-4], 0     ; signed int foo =0;
00401016   MOV     EAX, DWORD PTR SS:[EBP+C]   ; if((foo = atoi(argv[1])) > 5) {goto blah;}
00401019   MOV     ECX, DWORD PTR DS:[EAX+4]
0040101C   PUSH    ECX
0040101D   CALL    atoitest.atoi
00401022   ADD     ESP, 4
00401025   MOV     DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-4], EAX
00401028   CMP     DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-4], 5
0040102C   JLE     SHORT atoitest.00401032
0040102E   JMP     SHORT atoitest.00401043
00401030   JMP     SHORT atoitest.00401043
00401032   PUSH    atoitest.0041218C           ; printf("notok");return 0;
00401037   CALL    atoitest.printf
0040103C   ADD     ESP, 4
0040103F   XOR     EAX, EAX
00401041   JMP     SHORT atoitest.00401055
00401043   PUSH    atoitest.00412194           ; printf("ok");return 1;
00401048   CALL    atoitest.printf
0040104D   ADD     ESP, 4
00401050   MOV     EAX, 1
00401055   MOV     ESP, EBP                    ; }
00401057   POP     EBP
00401058   RETN
```

the same src code compiled with msvc /O1 does away all saves

**cl /Zi /O1 /EHsc /nologo /W4 /analyze *.cpp /link /RELEASE**

```
00401000 a>CMP     DWORD PTR SS:[ESP+4], 2     ; {
00401005   JE      SHORT atoitest.0040100B
00401007   OR      EAX, FFFFFFFF
0040100A   RETN                                ; }
0040100B   MOV     EAX, DWORD PTR SS:[ESP+8]   ; if((foo = atoi(argv[1])) > 5) {goto blah;}
0040100F   PUSH    DWORD PTR DS:[EAX+4]
00401012   CALL    atoitest.atoi
00401017   POP     ECX
00401018   CMP     EAX, 5
0040101B   JLE     SHORT atoitest.0040102C
0040101D   PUSH    atoitest.00412194           ; printf("ok");return 1;
00401022   CALL    atoitest.printf
00401027   XOR     EAX, EAX
00401029   INC     EAX
0040102A   POP     ECX
0040102B   RETN                                ; }
0040102C   PUSH    atoitest.0041218C           ; printf("notok");return 0;
00401031   CALL    atoitest.printf
00401036   XOR     EAX, EAX
00401038   POP     ECX
00401039   RETN                                ; }
```

same code with single exit and no gotos

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main (int argc , char* argv[]) {
  if(argc==2)  {
    int foo =0;
    if((foo = atoi(argv[1])) > 5) {
      printf("ok");
    } else {
      printf("notok");
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

unoptimesed compilation

```
00401000 a>PUSH    EBP                         ; int main (int argc , char* argv[]) {
00401001   MOV     EBP, ESP
00401003   PUSH    ECX
00401004   CMP     DWORD PTR SS:[EBP+8], 2     ; if(argc==2)  {
00401008   JNZ     SHORT atoitest.00401045
0040100A   MOV     DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-4], 0     ; int foo =0;
00401011   MOV     EAX, DWORD PTR SS:[EBP+C]   ; if((foo = atoi(argv[1])) > 5) {
00401014   MOV     ECX, DWORD PTR DS:[EAX+4]
00401017   PUSH    ECX
00401018   CALL    atoitest.atoi
0040101D   ADD     ESP, 4
00401020   MOV     DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-4], EAX
00401023   CMP     DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-4], 5
00401027   JLE     SHORT atoitest.00401038
00401029   PUSH    atoitest.0041218C           ; printf("ok");
0040102E   CALL    atoitest.printf
00401033   ADD     ESP, 4
00401036   JMP     SHORT atoitest.00401045     ; } else {
00401038   PUSH    atoitest.00412190           ; printf("notok");
0040103D   CALL    atoitest.printf
00401042   ADD     ESP, 4
00401045   XOR     EAX, EAX                    ; return 0;
00401047   MOV     ESP, EBP                    ; }
00401049   POP     EBP
0040104A   RETN
```

optimised compilation

```
00401000 a>CMP     DWORD PTR SS:[ESP+4], 2     ; int main (int argc , char* argv[]) {
00401005   JNZ     SHORT atoitest.0040102B
00401007   MOV     EAX, DWORD PTR SS:[ESP+8]   ; if((foo = atoi(argv[1])) > 5) {
0040100B   PUSH    DWORD PTR DS:[EAX+4]
0040100E   CALL    atoitest.atoi
00401013   POP     ECX
00401014   CMP     EAX, 5
00401017   JLE     SHORT atoitest.00401020
00401019   PUSH    atoitest.00412194           ; printf("ok");
0040101E   JMP     SHORT atoitest.00401025     ; } else {
00401020   PUSH    atoitest.0041218C           ; printf("notok");
00401025   CALL    atoitest.printf
0040102A   POP     ECX
0040102B   XOR     EAX, EAX                    ; return 0;
0040102D   RETN                                ; }
```

Answer (score 2):

The part before the call to `atoi` gets the content of `argv[1]` on the stack:

- `mov ecx, [ebp+argv]` gets `argv` into `ecx`
- `mov edx, [ecx+4]` gets `argv[1]` into `edx` - note `argv` is an array of pointers, each 4 bytes in size, so `[ecx+4]` is the "first" (counting from 0) element
- `push edx` puts it on the stack as the argument to `atoi`.

C functions return their result in `eax`*, so the `mov [ebp+var_60], eax` instruction saves the result of `atoi(argv[1])` to a local variable.

We can't know why that result is compared to `5`, this is part of the application logic. If that application was a crackme, and part of the challenge is "find out which number to give as a command line argument to make the program do something special", then `5` would be a good candidate for that special number.

(*) in most cases, unless they don't fit there, for example in the case of doubles or structs.

Comment: Great answer, thank you. It's nice to know C functions return their result to eax; I had forgotten.